# Make the same grayscale image appear in different colours in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, color, images, grayscale, tiff

I have seen an old InDesign file link to the same tiff image but have it in different colours just by applying those colours on the object's frame within InDesign. The tiff file itself was a 8-bit grayscale image when I opened it in Photoshop.

I am unable to replicate this result by creating fresh files. Does anyone know about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, Place your image and make sure it actually *is* grayscale. You can do that by looking at the link info in the Links panel.

[image: Grayscale Image]

Setting the fill color on the *frame* will change the fill of the whole frame and any white parts of your grayscale image.

[image: Set Frame Fill Color]

Selecting the image within the frame and setting the fill color will change the color of the black parts of your image.

[image: Set Image Fill Color]

Comment: THANK YOU! What's amazing is that it even works with JPEG format grayscale images. What I was doing wrong was that I was applying the colour only to the frame but not the content. I didn't realise that the two methods work on different parts of the image.