# How to achieve 2 chosen hue colour separation profile?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, photoshop-effects, color-separation

I'm really into the ColorLibrary colour separation profiles e.g. http://colorlibrary.ch/#blue-yellow

I wanted to use the blue and yellow one in a offset printed 2 colour book project, but as a student I don't have 40chf spare to purchase one. Does anyone has any ideas about how I would be able to achieve this effect myself? Tried googling but might be using the wrong terms. Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I must say that whoever made the page you linked to is not the brightest guy in the world. Man the page eats up your bandwidth like candy for almost no reason

Comment: Note thet 40 chf is not much money, if you spend severalhours waiting for an answer then 40 chf is a small sum

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/77703/preparing-design-for-duotone-printing/77708#77708

Comment: Read the other responses before you comment! These processed images are based on the original hues, not just a greyscale image..

Answer (score 1):

In photoshop:
Image > mode > multichannel

Then, in your channels panel you can add, remove and adjust channels. As for the exact result, you have to experiment some based on your photograph and the desired result. Also, read through the [documentation on the website you provided](http://colorlibrary.ch/how-to-install/) - even without buying the color library profiles, the principles are the same.

Edit: A small tutorial

Set your image mode to multichannel. Go to the channels panel, where you now have Cyan, Magenta and Yellow. Double click each one to change the color. Try picking spot colors from the color libraries instead of using the picker. Experiment with the number of channels and their solidity. I came a long way just by changing the magenta channel to grey and making cyan a little darker blue. And remember, what may work in one photo, might not work in every one. I haven't worked much in this mode, but my guess is that every photo needs a bit of work.

Comment: Thank a lot for getting back to me. Am I correct thinking you're suggesting something like this? https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/printing-spot-colors.html

Comment: That is a good reference for the panel I'm talking about and its different tools. I added a small tutorial in my initial answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just convert your image to a duotone in Photoshop.

See [Use duotones in Photoshop - Adobe Support](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/duotones.html)...

1. Convert your image to Grayscale *(Image → Mode → Grayscale)*. You can use a Black & White adjustment layer first to control the conversion to grayscale if needs be.
2. Convert your image to Duotone *(Image → Mode → Duotone)*. Select the correct type for the number of colors you want to use, set those colors and adjust the curves for each color until your happy with the result. Duotones are single channel images so if you need to create the separations yourself...
3. Convert your image to Multichannel mode *(Image → Mode → Multichannel)*. This will separate your image in to the correct channels for each ink/plate/color.

A quick example...

[image]

Image 1: Original image

[image]

Image 2: Converting to Duotone

[image]

Image 3: Multichannel separations

---

<sup>Image source: https://www.pexels.com/photo/beautiful-blur-camera-capture-348528/</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the response but the ones in colorlibrary are different - they aren't just duotone based on a greyscale image, it's more complex and based on the original colours of the image - take a look back at the site - http://colorlibrary.ch/#blue-yellow

Comment: @zackwxyz dont accept posts that dont answer your question. Anyway your looking at differently spread tone.

Comment: @zackwxyz the output you get from ColorLibrary is the same as you get from what I explained; a multichannel file using colors other than CMYK (or whatever the input is). All the ColorLibrary profile does is do the channel adjustments etc for you.

Comment: I don’t know how ColorLibrary converts the colors but this is the easiest way to do it without a profile

Comment: sorry, new to the site, thought I was liking the response. yes you get a multichannel file using non CMYK colors but the output isn't the same visually. Thanks for your suggestion, but I was looking for how to do that specific method of separation. I think the other answer is closer to what I'm looking for but just trying to get my head around how to do it - not worked with channels before. Anyway, good to know that there are simple ways of achieving something similar, cheers.

Comment: @zackwxyz the other answer is suggesting the same as me just without using a duotone to create the channels; the result is the same, a duotone is just an easy way to create the channels and adjustments in a single step, rather than doing it all manually

Answer (score 0):

One bad news. A lot of those images you are linking are not duotones... they are tritones. One Blue, yellow and black.

But let's see the color separations.

Using only one grayscale image is not good enough.

Take a look at this two posts:

[Preparing design for duotone printing?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/77703/preparing-design-for-duotone-printing/77708#77708)

[Printing photographs when job is a 2 spot color job](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/97123/printing-photographs-when-job-is-a-2-spot-color-job/97136#97136)

The basic idea is: take one "pure" channel, any of the RGB ones and use it as an ink. Use the opposite color.

On those two links I posted, I use one grayscale image as a base and one pure channel to do the "coloring".

But as you do not have a yellow channel I combined the Red and Green channel with multiply at the same time and used it as Blue. Then I used the blue as the yellow.

[image]

---

You also can tweak your CMYK color profile to reduce the amount of black used on the conversion.

Go to Edit>Color adjustments (May+Ctrl+K) And in the CMYK profile choose the [image]custom profile. PLay with the settings there.

Then you can replace one ink with another color using multichannels.