# Pantone colour shades

Tags: color, pantone

Is there some sort of secret way I don't know about to easily identify related shades of a Pantone colour (i.e. lighter / darker within the same colour) ?

The underlying use is creating a theme palette, and so I'm looking at defining both colours and shades within those "core" colours.

Comment: I don't understand this question. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "related shades"? A Pantone color is a physical ink. It's darkest at 100% and only gets lighter if you use lower percentages. Are you talking about finding *other* Pantone inks which can be seen as "related" to a given Pantone color?

Comment: Perhaps you need a [Pantone Color Guide](https://www.pantone-colours.com/index_bestanden/colours.jpg), which displays color on cards next to similar colors? Just guessing.. not really sure what's being asked either. As Wolff points out a single Pantone color can **only** get lighter, unless it is overprinted on top of another color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only lighten a Pantone color using percentages. In a printed project these percentages make the dot of the halftone smaller or bigger.

You can previsualize it on your software, which will simulate making it lighter.

---

The only way to darken a color is by using another darker ink, or at some extent using a complementary color, so you now have a duotone.

You can simulate it using multiply blending mode on the software you are using, but it is only an approximation. In the simulation, you can "cancel" a color making it black, in real life you can not achieve this, that is one reason to add black on a CMY print.

---

A pallet can be the result of combining two perpendicular gradients.

[image]

But again, it is only an approximation.

---

> identify related shades of a Pantone color

This is relative. Orange can be related to yellow, they are different inks but both are "warm".

But comes to my mind a post I wrote some time ago, about not using a light Pantone color, but using one similar at some percentage, and now you have the original color as one more "darker". Take a look: [Printing photographs when job is a 2 spot color job](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/97123/printing-photographs-when-job-is-a-2-spot-color-job/97136#97136)