# How to find a paint color that corresponds to pantone swatch?

Tags: color, pantone, painting

I have a fabricator who needs me to send paint colors that match the pantone shades i'm using in an illustrator document. The colors are 7495c 60% tint and 611 20%tint. Is there an easy way for me to match these colors, or am I going to need to sort through a bunch of paint samples?

Comment: Paints are RAL coded, there is a bunch of Pantone to RAL converter online to find, if its what you mean.

Comment: Take a Pantone color chip to a local paint store, ask them to match it and provide you with the formula used.... often you can purchase small sample pints of paint fairly inexpensively. So match, get a sample pint, and test to be certain it's correct when it dries.

Comment: I wouldn't start with an 80 or 20% pantone. I'd start with a 100% of an actual pantone tint [ie, plus white] of your desired colour . Less margin for error, assuming everything else is properly calibrated.

Comment: I agree that using tints of two Pantone colors seems like a pity if you have the possibility to choose lighter colors and use them at 100% instead. Looks much better as solids and easier to communicate to others when trying to find the right RAL color.

Answer (score 0):

Converting Illustrator's Pantone tints to solid paints looks quite a lottery. I guess you have nothing physical, only a file, but you need the tint as paint and want a simple mixing formula like "20% tint = 20% solid color and 80% white, shake 2 minutes"

You will not get it here - Tints in Illustrator try to imitate the look when solid color is printed on white paper with a dense raster and by leaving white between colored dots. Knowing usual print methods and how inks and papers behave makes possible to create somehow acceptable prediction of the result. But the result of mixing liquid paints depends heavily on the used paint materials and no general rule exists for the color of the mixing result.

I continue guessing: Your best option is to search for the most same looking solid Pantone by browsing the color book in Illustrator and making comparison tests. Have side by side a rectangle colored with the tint an another which you color with solid Pantones until a close enough version is found.

Know that uncalibrated screen very likely shows something different than what can be seen in a real Pantone color book (sold by Pantone). That book shows the actual meanings of Pantone codes. If possible, check also the found solid color in the real Pantone book.

If you like the found solid Pantone color you can pick it's code and find a good RAL color paint with a web Pantone code to RAL code converter as suggested already by others.

Theoretically you can go to a paint shop with a real Pantone book and say "I want this color made of paint material XXX(right for the job)". Do not try it if you have only the Pantone code, but not the real Pantone book. In that case you have better possiblilities if you have a good RAL code to tell.

Some paint webshop probably can mix for you something (no guarantee nor experience what it would be) if you tell the wanted Pantone code. If you find one who advertises "Pantone matching paints" it can be worth asking. Check also with the Wayback Machine how long they have survived with it.

Comment: It might be worth trying the ColorSnap app from Sherwin-Williams. Snap the pantone chip and see if it comes up with anything close to matching.  'Course, it's only good with Sherwin-Williams paints.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a spectrometer or colorimeter. The official from Pantone is insanely expensive.

https://www.pantone.com/pantone-capsure

So start looking at probably one that can read printed samples in some color space that you can convert on Illustrator.

Then take it to the print shop and start measuring samples of paint.

You can find some in Amazon that gives you a Lab color and at a decent price. So take a look.

---

One additional problem you have is that you need to target a tint, and you will have trouble with that because normally you will find solid colors. Probably you need to print a sample of the tones.

If you did that as an identity branding... you did it wrong, because an identity color guide should be mainly on solid colors.

There is a chance you can get the % tones with transparent ink, and not screening the tones.

Take a look at this: so you can sort of finding a Pantone equivalent to a shaded one: [Printing photographs when job is a 2 spot color job](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/97123/printing-photographs-when-job-is-a-2-spot-color-job/97136#97136)

---

Updated sometime later.

Here is a website that has and compares different paint systems. https://www.myperfectcolor.com/